# Background set to scrolling to end of image and then set to fixed

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
background-image: url(http://fehlbelichtet.stefanwensing.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/04/alte-strasse-endlos.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;


h1 {
 color: #e29532;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size: 60px;
 line-height: 50px;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align:center;
}

h2 {
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 color:#e29532;
}

p {
 font-family:verdana;
}

b  {
 font-size: 110%;
}

#topsection{
background: #dddce1;
height: 100px; /*Height of top section*/
margin:0;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 200px 0 230px; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/

}


#footer{
clear: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
color: white;
}

.innertube{
margin:0;
}
@media (max-width: 840px){ /* 1st level responsive layout break point- drop right column down*/


 
 #contentcolumn{
 margin-right: 0; /*Set margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
 }
}

@media (max-width: 600px){ /* 2nd level responsive layout break point- drop left column down */
 
 
 #contentcolumn{
 margin-left: 0;
 }
}

label {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  padding-top:0.2em;
  text-align:right;
  font-family:verdana
 }

fieldset {
 border-radius:4px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 font-family:verdanda;
 color:white;
}

legend {
 
}

input {
 border-radius:4px;
} 

select {
 border-radius:4px;
}

textarea {
 opacity:0.8;
 border-radius:4 px;
 font-family:verdana;
}

table {
 font-family:verdana;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Vinn en Bil!</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="volvo.ico"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

 <body>
  <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="topsection">
     <div class="innertube">
     
      <h1> Vinn en bil </h1>
      <hr>
      

     </div>
    </div>

   <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
     <div class="innertube"> 
      <br>
      <form>
       <fieldset class="fieldset"> 
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Personlig Information</h2>
        
         <br>
         
         <label for="namn">Förnamn:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Förnamn" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Förnamn'" required />
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="efternamn">Efternamn:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Efternamn" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Efternamn'" required />
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="age">Ålder: </label>
         <select name="age">
          <option value="18-25">18-25</option>
          <option value="25-35">25-35</option>
          <option value="35-50">35-50</option>
          <option value="50+">50+</option>
         </select>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="kön">Kön:</label>
         
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>Man</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Kvinna</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Annat</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         
         <br>
         
         <label for="mail">Email:</label>
         <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'" required/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="adress">Adress:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Adress" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Adress'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="postnummer">Postnummer:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Postnummer" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postnummer'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="postort">Postort:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Postort" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postort'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="nummer">Telefon nummer:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Telefon nummer" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Telefon nummer'"/>
        <br>
       </fieldset>
       
       <br>
       <br>
       
       
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Om du vann?</h2>
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>Välj en bil</td>
           
           <td>
            <div class="form-group">
             <select name="make" id="make">
              <option value="">Välj en Volvo typ</option>
              <option value="XC">XC</option>
              <option value="V">V</option>
              <option value="S">S</option>
              <option value="Laddhybrider">Laddhybrider</option>
             </select>  
            </div>
           </td>
           
           <td>
            <div class="from-group">
             <select name="type" id="type">
              <option value="" class="">Välj en Volvo model </option>
              <option value="XC90" class="XC">XC90</option>
              <option value="XC60" class="XC">XC60</option>
              <option value="V60 Cross country" class="V">V90 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V90" class="V">V90</option>
              <option value="V60 Cross country" class="V">V60 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V60" class="V">V60</option>
              <option value="V40 Cross country" class="V">V40 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V40" class="V">V40</option>
              <option value="S90" class="S">S90</option>
              <option value="S60 Cross country" class="S">S60 Cross country</option>
              <option value="S60" class="S">S60</option>
              <option value="XC90 T8 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">XC90 T8 Twin engine</option>
              <option value="V60 D6 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">V60 D6 Twin engine</option>
              <option value="V60 D5 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">V60 D5 Twin engine</option>  
             </select>
            </div>  
           </td>
          </tr> 
         </table>

         <br>
         
         <p>Varför ska just du ska vinna:</p>
         <textarea rows="20" cols="60"></textarea> 
         
        <br>
        <br>
        
       </fieldset>
       
       <br>
       <br>
       
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Omdöme på hemsidan</h2> 
         
         <br>
         
         <p>Vad tycker du om sidan</p>
         <textarea rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
         
         
         
         
         
         <input type="submit" value="Klar" onclick="alert('Tack för ditt deltagande!')">
         <input type="reset">
      </form>
     </div>  
    </div>
   </div>


   <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.volvocars.com/se?gclid=Cj0KEQjwqMHABRDVl6_hqKGDyNIBEiQAN-O9hMtUPMIE4aak0QmcGyXpDihhM-HkAJVCuGxwqf7fpQUaAmVb8P8HAQ" target="_blank">Volvo</a></div>

  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

my background-attachment is set to fixed and I want the website to scroll down to then end of the image and then be set to fixed.

I'm new to coding and this website is local and is just on my coumputer so put the link to the image in url for background-image.

Comment: Are you talking about parallax ?

Comment: Please put the code in relevant parts of the snippet so it runs and then click tidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace css property background with background image. Add  background-size and    background-position

```css
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height: 1.5em;
background: url(http://fehlbelichtet.stefanwensing.de/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2016/04/alte-strasse-endlos.jpg); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
 


h1 {
 color: #e29532;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 font-size: 60px;
 line-height: 50px;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align:center;
}

h2 {
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:verdana;
 color:#e29532;
}

p {
 font-family:verdana;
}

b  {
 font-size: 110%;
}

#topsection{
background: #dddce1;
height: 100px; /*Height of top section*/
margin:0;
}

#contentwrapper{
float: left;
width: 100%;
}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 200px 0 230px; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/

}


#footer{
clear: left;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 4px 0;
}

#footer a{
color: white;
}

.innertube{
margin:0;
}
@media (max-width: 840px){ /* 1st level responsive layout break point- drop right column down*/


 
 #contentcolumn{
 margin-right: 0; /*Set margin to LeftColumnWidth*/
 }
}

@media (max-width: 600px){ /* 2nd level responsive layout break point- drop left column down */
 
 
 #contentcolumn{
 margin-left: 0;
 }
}

label {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  padding-top:0.2em;
  text-align:right;
  font-family:verdana
 }

fieldset {
 border-radius:4px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
 font-family:verdanda;
 color:white;
}

legend {
 
}

input {
 border-radius:4px;
} 

select {
 border-radius:4px;
}

textarea {
 opacity:0.8;
 border-radius:4 px;
 font-family:verdana;
}

table {
 font-family:verdana;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Vinn en Bil!</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="volvo.ico"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

 <body>
  <div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="topsection">
     <div class="innertube">
     
      <h1> Vinn en bil </h1>
      <hr>
      

     </div>
    </div>

   <div id="contentwrapper">
    <div id="contentcolumn">
     <div class="innertube"> 
      <br>
      <form>
       <fieldset class="fieldset"> 
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Personlig Information</h2>
        
         <br>
         
         <label for="namn">Förnamn:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Förnamn" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Förnamn'" required />
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="efternamn">Efternamn:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Efternamn" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Efternamn'" required />
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="age">Ålder: </label>
         <select name="age">
          <option value="18-25">18-25</option>
          <option value="25-35">25-35</option>
          <option value="35-50">35-50</option>
          <option value="50+">50+</option>
         </select>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="kön">Kön:</label>
         
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>Man</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Kvinna</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
           <td>Annat</td>
           <td><input class="radio" type="radio"></input></td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         
         <br>
         
         <label for="mail">Email:</label>
         <input type="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Email'" required/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="adress">Adress:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Adress" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Adress'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="postnummer">Postnummer:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Postnummer" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postnummer'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="postort">Postort:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Postort" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Postort'"/>
         
         <br>
         <br>
         
         <label for="nummer">Telefon nummer:</label>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Telefon nummer" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Telefon nummer'"/>
        <br>
       </fieldset>
       
       <br>
       <br>
       
       
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Om du vann?</h2>
         <table>
          <tr>
           <td>Välj en bil</td>
           
           <td>
            <div class="form-group">
             <select name="make" id="make">
              <option value="">Välj en Volvo typ</option>
              <option value="XC">XC</option>
              <option value="V">V</option>
              <option value="S">S</option>
              <option value="Laddhybrider">Laddhybrider</option>
             </select>  
            </div>
           </td>
           
           <td>
            <div class="from-group">
             <select name="type" id="type">
              <option value="" class="">Välj en Volvo model </option>
              <option value="XC90" class="XC">XC90</option>
              <option value="XC60" class="XC">XC60</option>
              <option value="V60 Cross country" class="V">V90 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V90" class="V">V90</option>
              <option value="V60 Cross country" class="V">V60 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V60" class="V">V60</option>
              <option value="V40 Cross country" class="V">V40 Cross country</option>
              <option value="V40" class="V">V40</option>
              <option value="S90" class="S">S90</option>
              <option value="S60 Cross country" class="S">S60 Cross country</option>
              <option value="S60" class="S">S60</option>
              <option value="XC90 T8 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">XC90 T8 Twin engine</option>
              <option value="V60 D6 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">V60 D6 Twin engine</option>
              <option value="V60 D5 Twin engine" class="Laddhybrider">V60 D5 Twin engine</option>  
             </select>
            </div>  
           </td>
          </tr> 
         </table>

         <br>
         
         <p>Varför ska just du ska vinna:</p>
         <textarea rows="20" cols="60"></textarea> 
         
        <br>
        <br>
        
       </fieldset>
       
       <br>
       <br>
       
       <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend></legend>
        <h2>Omdöme på hemsidan</h2> 
         
         <br>
         
         <p>Vad tycker du om sidan</p>
         <textarea rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>
         
         
         
         
         
         <input type="submit" value="Klar" onclick="alert('Tack för ditt deltagande!')">
         <input type="reset">
      </form>
     </div>  
    </div>
   </div>


   <div id="footer"><a href="http://www.volvocars.com/se?gclid=Cj0KEQjwqMHABRDVl6_hqKGDyNIBEiQAN-O9hMtUPMIE4aak0QmcGyXpDihhM-HkAJVCuGxwqf7fpQUaAmVb8P8HAQ" target="_blank">Volvo</a></div>

  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this awesome tutorial [css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-fix-content/)